# 404 Cannot Post (Postman and Mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I am trying to create a database of users for my app. I used the same code I used for my other routes that seem to be working fine but for some reason I keep getting a 404 error from postman when I try to create a new user. I am still learning js so this could be a silly mistake but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. This is my code, any help is greatly appreciated!

users.js (the route):

```js
const _ = require('lodash') 
const {User, validate} = require('../models/user') 
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
const express = require('express'); 
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    const { error } = validate(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

    let user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
    if (user) return res.status(400).send('User already registered')
    
    user = new User(_.pick(req.body,['name', 'email', 'password']))
    await user.save();

    res.send(_.pick(user, ['_id','name', 'email'])); });

module.exports = router;
```

user.js (the model)

```js
const Joi = require('joi'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const User = mongoose.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 50},
    email: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 255, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 1024}   }))


  function validateUser(user) {
    const schema = {
      name: Joi.string().min(5).max(50).required(),
      email: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required().email(),
      password: Joi.string().min(5).max(255).required()
    };
  
    return Joi.validate(user, schema);   }

  exports.User = User;   exports.validate = validateUser;
```

index.js:

```js
const Joi = require('joi') Joi.objectId = require('joi-objectid')(Joi) const mongoose = require("mongoose") 
const express = require("express"); 
const app = express(); 
const genres = require("./routes/genres"); 
const customers = require("./routes/customers") 
const movies = require("./routes/movies") 
const rentals = require("./routes/rentals") 
const users = require("./routes/users")

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/vidly")
    .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
    .catch(err => console.log("Could not connect to MongoDB")) 

app.use(express.json()); 
app.use("/api/genres", genres); 
app.use("/api/customers", customers); 
app.use("/api/movies", movies); 
app.use("/api/rentals", rentals); 
app.use("api/users", users)


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

Comment: can you tell what is the exact URL you're trying in postman......... nd you're also missing `/` in index.js near `app.use("api/users", users)`

Comment: that was it! the / , I feel so silly. thanks so much for your help